# List of different values which have to be formatted differently

Tags: list-manipulation, output-formatting

I have a large list of values which – for presentation in my LaTeX document – I need to format. For instance: I have calculated growth rates which I now would like to have formatted in the form of:

```
   In[2260]:= Map[{First[First[#]],NumberForm[N[Last[#]],3,2}]}&,
                CompleteQuarterlyStatDataBySubjects[[1]][[1]]]

    Out[2260]= {{Australia,{}},{Austria,-1.21},{Belgium,-1.46},{Canada,-1.30},
       {Czech Republic,-1.67},{Denmark,-1.87},{Estonia,-3.97},{Finland,-2.53},
       {France,-1.00},{Germany,-1.74},{Greece,-1.16},{Hungary,-1.45},
       {Iceland,-1.83}, {Ireland,-1.67},{Israel,{}},{Italy,-1.42},{Japan,-0.69},
       {Korea, {}},{Luxembourg,-1.67},{Netherlands,-0.98},{New Zealand,-0.50},
       {Norway,-0.64},{Poland,{}},{Portugal,-0.40},{Slovak Republic,{}},
       {Slovenia,-3.31},{Spain,-0.71},{Sweden,{}},{Switzerland,-0.82},
       {Turkey,-3.39},{United Kingdom,-1.45},{United States,-1.28}}
```

(the original dataset `CompleteQuarterlyStatDataBySubjects[[1]][[1]]` is at the bottom of this post)

Besides growth rates I have calculated `AbsoluteTime`-Values which I would like to format as follows:

```
In[2271]:= Map[
             {
              First[First[#]],
              Table[
                DateString[#[[2;;-1]][[i]],{"Quarter"," ","Year"}],
                {i,Length[#[[2;;-1]]]}
              ]
             }&,
             CompleteQuarterlyStatDataBySubjects[[1]][[5]]
           ]

Out[2271]= {{Australia,{DateString[{},{Quarter, ,Year}]}},{Austria,{1 2008}},
            {Belgium,{2 2008}},{Canada,{3 2008}},{Czech Republic,{3 2008}},
            {Denmark,{2 2008}},{Estonia,{2 2008}},{Finland,{2 2008}},
            {France,{1 2008}},{Germany,{1 2008}},{Greece,{3 2008}},
            {Hungary,{1 2008}},{Iceland,{3 2008}},{Ireland,{4 2007}},
            {Israel,{DateString[{},{Quarter, ,Year}]}},{Italy,{1 2008}},
            {Japan,{1 2008,3 2010}},{Korea,{DateString[{},{Quarter, ,Year}]}},
            {Luxembourg,{1 2008}},{Netherlands,{1 2008}},{New Zealand,{4 2007}},
            {Norway,{2 2008}},{Poland,{DateString[{},{Quarter, ,Year}]}},
            {Portugal,{4 2007,3 2010}},{Slovak Republic,{DateString[{},
            {Quarter, ,Year}]}},{Slovenia,{3 2008}},{Spain,{1 2008}},
            {Sweden,{DateString[{},{Quarter, ,Year}]}},{Switzerland,{2 2008}},
            {Turkey,{1 2008}},{United Kingdom,{1 2008}},{United States,{2 2008}}}
```

To automate the process of getting the values into the right format, I thought to use the following approach:

```
In[2261]:= Formats[list_,x_]:=
    If[x==1,
    NumberForm[N[list],{3,2}]
       If[x==5,
       Table[DateString[list[[i]],{"Quarter"," ","Year"}],{i,Length[list]}]
       ]
    ]
```

And then to type for example:

```
    Map[
      {
        First[First[#]],
        Formats[Last[#],1]
      }&,
      CompleteQuarterlyStatDataBySubjects[[1]][[1]]
    ]
```

Unfortunately that did not work! Does anyone has an idea how I can program a procedure to get my data automatically formatted?

The original data is:

```
 In[2259]:= CompleteQuarterlyStatDataBySubjects[[1]][[1]]
    Out[2259]= {{{Australia,AUS,other countries,GDP,quarterly data},{}},{{Austria,AUT,western European
    countries,GDP,quarterly data},-1.2056},{{Belgium,BEL,western European
    countries,GDP,quarterly data},-(7288960271654/4985881289361)},{{Canada,CAN,G7,GDP,quarterly data},-1.30053},{{Czech Republic,CZE,eastern European
    countries,GDP,quarterly data},-(2134917223477606900/1282008490172233089)},{{Denmark,DNK,nothern European
    countries,GDP,quarterly data},-(48057014595630800665/25700334274612164804)},{{Estonia,EST,eastern European
    countries,GDP,quarterly data},-3.9659},{{Finland,FIN,nothern European
    countries,GDP,quarterly data},-(33199059446612625/13128459048331036)},{{France,FRA,G7,GDP,quarterly data},-(5130109517723890585/5148852459134416857)},{{Germany,DEU,G7,GDP,quarterly data},-1.73904},{{Greece,GRC,southern European
    countries,GDP,quarterly data},-1.164},{{Hungary,HUN,eastern European
    countries,GDP,quarterly data},-(2225003087375671762980417961289391847/1539154631936274189423508152574973424)},{{Iceland,ISL,nothern European
    countries,GDP,quarterly data},-1.83398},{{Ireland,IRL,nothern European
    countries,GDP,quarterly data},-1.67021},{{Israel,ISR,other countries,GDP,quarterly data},{}},{{Italy,ITA,G7,GDP,quarterly data},-1.42009},{{Japan,JPN,G7,GDP,quarterly data},-(673269612770377724744620/262544695052599501095431),-(32760683814040103590/47201698472568566589)},{{Korea,KOR,other countries,GDP,quarterly data},{}},{{Luxembourg,LUX,western European
    countries,GDP,quarterly data},-1.67073},{{Netherlands,NLD,western European
    countries,GDP,quarterly data},-0.97505},{{New Zealand,NZL,other countries,GDP,quarterly data},-(152151059187768664247/302333262014074402254)},{{Norway,NOR,nothern European
    countries,GDP,quarterly data},-(33596749386427335752225/52657796909983176600514)},{{Poland,POL,eastern European
    countries,GDP,quarterly data},{}},{{Portugal,PRT,southern European
    countries,GDP,quarterly data},-0.785963,-0.398132},{{Slovak Republic,SVK,eastern European
    countries,GDP,quarterly data},{}},{{Slovenia,SVN,eastern European
    countries,GDP,quarterly data},-3.31102},{{Spain,ESP,southern European
    countries,GDP,quarterly data},-(2414923435622638997136189344226575/3392598745831412249336953513454508)},{{Sweden,SWE,nothern European
    countries,GDP,quarterly data},{}},{{Switzerland,CHE,western European
    countries,GDP,quarterly data},-0.820439},{{Turkey,TUR,other countries,GDP,quarterly data},-3.38638},{{United Kingdom,GBR,G7,GDP,quarterly data},-(2047013335956949212233044315/1411710881613564347284381614)},{{United States,USA,G7,GDP,quarterly data},-(2091354065961931475/1636350606517650408)}}
```

and for the AbsoluteTime-Values:

```
In[2265]:= CompleteQuarterlyStatDataBySubjects[[1]][[5]]
Out[2265]= {{{Australia,AUS,other countries,GDP,quarterly data},{}},{{Austria,AUT,western European
countries,GDP,quarterly data},3408134400},{{Belgium,BEL,western European
countries,GDP,quarterly data},3415996800},{{Canada,CAN,G7,GDP,quarterly data},3423859200},{{Czech Republic,CZE,eastern European
countries,GDP,quarterly data},3423859200},{{Denmark,DNK,nothern European
countries,GDP,quarterly data},3415996800},{{Estonia,EST,eastern European
countries,GDP,quarterly data},3415996800},{{Finland,FIN,nothern European
countries,GDP,quarterly data},3415996800},{{France,FRA,G7,GDP,quarterly data},3408134400},{{Germany,DEU,G7,GDP,quarterly data},3408134400},{{Greece,GRC,southern European
countries,GDP,quarterly data},3423859200},{{Hungary,HUN,eastern European
countries,GDP,quarterly data},3408134400},{{Iceland,ISL,nothern European
countries,GDP,quarterly data},3423859200},{{Ireland,IRL,nothern European
countries,GDP,quarterly data},3400185600},{{Israel,ISR,other countries,GDP,quarterly data},{}},{{Italy,ITA,G7,GDP,quarterly data},3408134400},{{Japan,JPN,G7,GDP,quarterly data},3408134400,3486931200},{{Korea,KOR,other countries,GDP,quarterly data},{}},{{Luxembourg,LUX,western European
countries,GDP,quarterly data},3408134400},{{Netherlands,NLD,western European
countries,GDP,quarterly data},3408134400},{{New Zealand,NZL,other countries,GDP,quarterly data},3400185600},{{Norway,NOR,nothern European
countries,GDP,quarterly data},3415996800},{{Poland,POL,eastern European
countries,GDP,quarterly data},{}},{{Portugal,PRT,southern European
countries,GDP,quarterly data},3400185600,3486931200},{{Slovak Republic,SVK,eastern European
countries,GDP,quarterly data},{}},{{Slovenia,SVN,eastern European
countries,GDP,quarterly data},3423859200},{{Spain,ESP,southern European
countries,GDP,quarterly data},3408134400},{{Sweden,SWE,nothern European
countries,GDP,quarterly data},{}},{{Switzerland,CHE,western European
countries,GDP,quarterly data},3415996800},{{Turkey,TUR,other countries,GDP,quarterly data},3408134400},{{United Kingdom,GBR,G7,GDP,quarterly data},3408134400},{{United States,USA,G7,GDP,quarterly data},3415996800}}
```

Comment: It is not clear what output you expect.  Do you desire a table with three columns: the country name, the growth rate, and the date?

Comment: I would like to have two tables each with two columns: country name & growth and country name & date.

Comment: Glad to see you made it over here. Don't forget to check out [meta](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com) for important discussions on how things work over here. In particular, here's a [summary](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/135/52) of some of them.

Answer (score 2):

(edit: you should use lower-case letters to start user function names so as not to conflict with built-ins.)

Please tell me if this does what you want:

```
formats[{}, _] = {};
formats[list_, 1] := NumberForm[N[list], {3, 2}]
formats[list_, 5] := DateString[list, {"Quarter", " ", "Year"}]
```

---

Testing.  With `dat1` set to your `Out[2259]=`, and `dat2` set to your `Out[2265]=` :

```
Map[{First[First[#]], formats[Last[#], 1]} &, dat1]
```

> {{Australia,{}},{Austria,-1.21},{Belgium,-1.46},{Canada,-1.30},{Czech
>   Republic,-1.67},{Denmark,-1.87},{Estonia,-3.97},{Finland,-2.53},{France,-1.00},{Germany,-1.74},{Greece,-1.16},{Hungary,-1.45},{Iceland,-1.83},{Ireland,-1.67},{Israel,{}},{Italy,-1.42},{Japan,-0.69},{Korea,{}},{Luxembourg,-1.67},{Netherlands,-0.98},{New
>   Zealand,-0.50},{Norway,-0.64},{Poland,{}},{Portugal,-0.40},{Republic
>   Slovak,{}},{Slovenia,-3.31},{Spain,-0.71},{Sweden,{}},{Switzerland,-0.82},{Turkey,-3.39},{Kingdom
>   United,-1.45},{States United,-1.28}}

```
Map[{First[First[#]], formats[Last[#], 5]} &, dat2]
```

> {{Australia, {}}, {Austria, "1 2008"}, {Belgium, "2 2008"}, {Canada,
>   "3 2008"}, {Czech Republic, "3 2008"}, {Denmark,    "2 2008"},
>   {Estonia, "2 2008"}, {Finland, "2 2008"}, {France,    "1 2008"},
>   {Germany, "1 2008"}, {Greece, "3 2008"}, {Hungary,    "1 2008"},
>   {Iceland, "3 2008"}, {Ireland,    "4 2007"}, {Israel, {}}, {Italy, "1
>   2008"}, {Japan,    "3 2010"}, {Korea, {}}, {Luxembourg, "1 2008"},
>   {Netherlands,    "1 2008"}, {New Zealand, "4 2007"}, {Norway,    "2
>   2008"}, {Poland, {}}, {Portugal,    "3 2010"}, {Republic Slovak, {}},
>   {Slovenia, "3 2008"}, {Spain,    "1 2008"}, {Sweden, {}},
>   {Switzerland, "2 2008"}, {Turkey,    "1 2008"}, {Kingdom United, "1
>   2008"}, {States United, "2 2008"}}

Comment: Ups. Missed that one, but this even though, it does not work.

Comment: @John please, what output are you expecting?  I have trouble understanding your intention.

Comment: The output should be as in Output[2260] and Output[2271]. Perhaps further explanation helps to understand:
As explained I have to cope with a large list of values, namely CompleteQuarterlyStatDataBySubjects[[j]][[i]]. As I am doing an econometric analysis this list contains 24 economic indicators (such as GDP and imports figures), whereas j stands for the indicators. In addition, for each indicator I have calculated 9  key figures (such as growth rates), represented by i. Each of this key figures need to be formatted in a different way as indicated in In[2260] and In[2271].

Comment: @John I have updated my answer.  I also included the output that I am seeing.  I hope that this does what you want.

Comment: @John please note that because your own data has the country names as Symbols, rather than Strings, there are things such as `States United` appearing in my output; I expect that this will not happen with your original data.